# Neovim code actions list with mason lsp by extension?

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig, nvim.cmp

Now I use mason to install all the lsp I need, and I use null_ls for diagnostic and fixing code. But I have problems with code actions, for example in jsx code I want to import useState, I call code actions but the list does not always have the action I need, although sometimes it is there, also there are a lot of unnecessary actions that are not needed for jsx code, for example there are actions related to styles - stylelint, but they are not needed in jsx. Can you tell me if it is possible to determine which servers will be connected by file extension? Or perhaps there are more convenient options for solving this problem?
[image]

Here's what my config with lsp looks like now

```
local lsp = require('lsp-zero').preset({})

lsp.set_preferences({
    suggest_lsp_servers = false,
    set_lsp_keymaps = false,
    sign_icons = {error = '☢️', warn = '⚠️', hint = 'H', info = 'I'}
})

lsp.ensure_installed({
    'lua_ls', 'tsserver', -- 'eslint',
    -- 'stylelint',
    -- 'html',
    -- 'prettier',
    'emmet_ls'
    -- 'cssls',
    -- 'cssmodules_ls',
})
local masontool = require('mason-tool-installer')
masontool.setup({
    ensure_installed = {
        'emmet-ls', 'eslint-lsp', 'json-lsp', 'lua-language-server',
        'stylelint-lsp', 'typescript-language-server'

    }
})

lsp.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
    lsp.default_keymaps({buffer = bufnr})
    local opts = {buffer = bufnr, remap = false}
    vim.keymap.set("n", "gt", function() vim.lsp.buf.definition() end, opts)
    vim.keymap.set("n", "gk", function() vim.lsp.buf.hover() end, opts)
    vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vws",
                   function() vim.lsp.buf.workspace_symbol() end, opts)
    -- vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vd", function() vim.diagnostic.open_float() end, opts)
    vim.keymap.set("n", "dn", function() vim.diagnostic.goto_next() end, opts)
    vim.keymap.set("n", "dp", function() vim.diagnostic.goto_prev() end, opts)
    vim.keymap
        .set("n", "<M-CR>", function() vim.lsp.buf.code_action() end, opts)
    -- vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vca", function() vim.lsp.buf.code_action() end,
    --                opts)
    vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vrr", function() vim.lsp.buf.references() end,
                   opts)
    vim.keymap
        .set("n", "<leader>vrn", function() vim.lsp.buf.rename() end, opts)
    vim.keymap.set("i", "<C-h>", function() vim.lsp.buf.signature_help() end,
                   opts)
end)

-- format
lsp.format_on_save({
    format_opts = {async = false, timeout_ms = 10000},
    servers = {
        ['null-ls'] = {
            'javascript', 'typescript', 'typescriptreact', 'javascriptreact',
            'json', 'lua', 'scss', 'html', 'css'
        }
    }
})

local null_ls = require("null-ls")

null_ls.setup({
    sources = {
        null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettier,
        null_ls.builtins.formatting.stylelint,
        null_ls.builtins.formatting.lua_format,
        null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.eslint,
        null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.stylelint,
        null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.luacheck
    }
})

local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')

-- emmet
-- local configs = require('lspconfig/configs')
local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
capabilities.textDocument.completion.completionItem.snippetSupport = true

lspconfig.emmet_ls.setup({
    -- on_attach = on_attach,
    capabilities = capabilities,
    filetypes = {
        'html', 'typescriptreact', 'javascriptreact', 'css', 'sass', 'scss',
        'less', 'lua'
    },
    init_options = {
        html = {
            options = {
                -- For possible options, see: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/src/config.ts#L79-L267
                ["bem.enabled"] = true
            }
        }
    }
})
lspconfig.lua_ls.setup(lsp.nvim_lua_ls())

lsp.setup()

local cmp = require('cmp')
local cmp_action = require('lsp-zero').cmp_action()
local luasnip = require("luasnip")
-- require("luasnip.loaders.from_lua").load({ paths = "~/.config/nvim/snippet/" })
-- require("luasnip.loaders.from_vscode").lazy_load()
require("luasnip.loaders.from_vscode").lazy_load {
    paths = {"~/.config/nvim/user/snippets/"}
}

--   פּ ﯟ   some other good icons
local kind_icons = {
    Text = "",
    Method = "m",
    Function = "",
    Constructor = "",
    Field = "",
    Variable = "",
    Class = "",
    Interface = "",
    Module = "",
    Property = "",
    Unit = "",
    Value = "",
    Enum = "",
    Keyword = "",
    Snippet = "",
    Color = "",
    File = "",
    Reference = "",
    Folder = "",
    EnumMember = "",
    Constant = "",
    Struct = "",
    Event = "",
    Operator = "",
    TypeParameter = ""
}

cmp.setup({
    snippet = {
        expand = function(args)
            luasnip.lsp_expand(args.body) -- For `luasnip` users.
        end
    },

    sources = {
        {name = "luasnip"}, {name = 'nvim_lsp'}, {name = 'path'},
        {name = 'emmet_ls'},
        -- {name = 'emmet-language-server', keyword_length = 4},
        {name = 'copilot'}, {name = 'buffer'}
    },
    window = {
        documentation = {
            border = {'╭', '─', '╮', '│', '╯', '─', '╰', '│'}
        },
        completion = {
            border = {'╭', '─', '╮', '│', '╯', '─', '╰', '│'},
            winhighlight = 'Normal:CmpPmenu,FloatBorder:CmpPmenuBorder,CursorLine:PmenuSel,Search:None'
        }
    },

    mapping = {
        ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({select = true}),
        ['<C-f>'] = cmp_action.luasnip_jump_forward(),
        ['<C-b>'] = cmp_action.luasnip_jump_backward()
    }

})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try with this: especify the code actions buffer you want in the setup

```
null_ls.setup({
     sources = {
         null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettier,
         null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.eslint_d.with({
         diagnostics_format = '[eslint] #{m}\n(#{c})'
      }),
      null_ls.builtins.code_actions.eslint_d
    }
})
```